# How to send the count value using JSON in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, get

I want to send the count value,for count the post i am using [thumbs up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem in ROR.

Now i want to send the count in json,the vote as post action in def show

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
respond_with(@posts) do |format|
  format.json { render json: @post_names = {:post => @posts.as_json(:only=> [:content, :title]) } }

end
end
```

I want to send the count value using json,because i want to show that count value in my client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send vote count by this way. I assume something like this can work..

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  respond_with(@posts) do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @post_names = {:post => @posts.map {|t| {:title => t.title, :content => t.content, :count => t.votes_for }} } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working on the controller, you might find it helpful to look at the [`render` section of the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

Comment: ,No dude,actually for voting i am using thumbs gem,how to send that count in json

Comment: Ezekiel is right -- if you want to send JSON, you render the json. You're setting a *ton* of instance variables here so unless ALL of them are going to be part of a giant JSON response then you need a separate controller method sending back just the data you want.